# println(char), characters turn into Chinese?

Tags: java

Please help me to troubleshoot this problem.

A have an input file 'Trial.txt' with content "Thanh Le".

Here is the function I used in an attempt to read from the file:

```
    public char[] importSeq(){
    File file = new File("G:\\trial.txt");

    char temp_seq[] = new char[100];

    try{
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
    BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
    DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(bis);

    int i = 0;

    //Try to read all character till the end of file
    while(dis.available() != 0){
        temp_seq[i]=dis.readChar();
        i++;
    }
    System.out.println(" imported");
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return temp_seq;
}
```

And the main function:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Sequence s1 = new Sequence();

    char result[];

    result = s1.importSeq();

    int i = 0;
    while(result[i] != 0){
        System.out.println(result[i]);
        i++;
    }
}
```

And this is the output.

run:

```
 imported
瑨
慮
栠
汥
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's honestly said a pretty clumsy way to read a text file into a `char[]`.

Here's a better example, assuming that the text file contains only ASCII characters.

```
File file = new File("G:/trial.txt");
char[] content = new char[(int) file.length()];
Reader reader = null;

try {
    reader = new FileReader(file);
    reader.read(content);
} finally {
    if (reader != null) try { reader.close(); } catch (IOException ignore) {}
}

return content;
```

And then to print the `char[]`, just do:

```
System.out.println(content);
```

Note that `InputStream#available()` doesn't necessarily do what you're expecting.

#### See also:

- [Java IO tutorial](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/essential/io/)

Comment: it workssssssssssssssssss!!!! Thank you. Yes it is clumsy... I am new to programming ... But thank you :)

Comment: You're welcome. In the future, try reading the right tutorials/books rather than stabbing around in the dark :)

Answer (score 3):

Because in Java a char is made by 2 bytes, so, when you use `readChar`, it will read pairs of letters and compose them into unicode characters.

You can avoid this by using `readByte(..)` instead..

Comment: Hi there, thank you for responding, when I tried to modify it to readByte(), "Uncompilable source code - possible loss of precision". Is there anyway to go around this? thank you

Comment: Also, when I change variable type to Byte[], it print numbers instead of chinese, not characters.

Comment: That's because bytes aren't characters.  In order to read characters properly, you'll need a FileReader or InputStreamReader, which uses an encoding (specified when you create the object, or usually defaulted to UTF-8) to translate bytes to chars.

Answer (score 1):

Some code to demonstrate, what exactly is happening. A `char` in Java consists of **two bytes** and represents **one character**, the glyph (pixels) you see on the screen. The default encoding in Java is UTF-16, one particular way to use two bytes to represent one of all the glyphs. Your file had **one byte** to represent **one character**, probably ASCII. When you read one UTF-16 character, **you read two bytes** and thus two ASCII characters from your file.

The following code tries to explain how single ASCII bytes 't' and 'h', become one chinese UTF-16 character.

```
public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println((int)'t'); // 116 == x74 (116 is 74 in Hex)
    System.out.println((int)'h'); // 104 == x68
    System.out.println((int)'瑨'); // 29800 == x7468

    // System.out.println('\u0074'); // t
    // System.out.println('\u0068'); // h
    // System.out.println('\u7468'); // 瑨

    char th = (('t' << 8) + 'h'); //x74 x68
    System.out.println(th); //瑨 == 29800 == '\u7468'

  }
}
```